# How to Drag an EasyUI Tree Node on to a Fabric.js Canvas?

Tags: javascript, tree, fabricjs, jquery-easyui

I have recently begun noodling with the **Jquery-EasyUI Framework** and I've come across a bit of a stumper... how can I drag a node out of an EasyUI Tree and into *another* object? (In my case, a Fabric.js Canvas) The EasyUI Tree object seems to be swallowing up any event which doesn't terminate inside the tree. All I want to be able to do upon dropping on the canvas (or anywhere else) is to either

**(A) (Most Preferable):** Get access to the "attributes" property of the EasyUI Tree node object that's getting dragged out of the tree

**(B) (Less Preferable):** To at least be able to get the ID or Text of the tree node object that's being dragged.

Right now, I'm getting nothing. As soon as the object is dragged outside the tree area, all I'm getting are null objects on the canvas (or anywhere else I try to set it up).

Does anybody know how this could be done?

Thanks!

I have stripped down my project to more or less the essential elements. When it runs it creates a frame with a left side containing an easyui tree and an easyui project grid, and a right side containing a Fabric.js canvas. What I would like to do is be able to drag an item from the tree and drop it onto the canvas and be able to (ideally) retrieve it's properties contained in the "attributes" attribute of the node, or else (at least) be able to retrieve the ID/Text value from the dropped node itself, which I could then lookup independently if necessary.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>EasyUI Drag-n-Drop Test</title>

  <style>
    body, html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding: 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        }
  </style>

  <!-- Load JQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Load EasyUI Framework -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">  
  <!-- Load Other Javascript Modules -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.1/fabric.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Direct / Inline Javascript for this Document -->
  <script type="text/javascript">


// Handle Tree & Canvas Drag & Drop Events
function handleStartDrag(e) {
    console.log('handleStartDrag');
    console.table(e);
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    alert('Drag-n-Dropped ['+text+']');
    return false;
};

function handleStopDrag(e) {
    console.log('handleStopDrag');
    console.table(e);
    return false;
};

function handleDragEnter(e) {
    console.log('handleDragEnter');
    console.table(e);
    return false;
};

function handleDragOver(e) {
    console.log('handleDragOver');
    console.table(e);
    return false;
};

function handleDragLeave(e) {
    console.log('handleDragLeave');
    console.table(e);
    return false;
};

function handleDrop(e) {
    console.log('handleDrop');
    console.table(e);
    var data = e.dataTransfer.getData('text');
    alert('Drag-n-Dropped ['+text+']');
    return false;
};

function loadFilter(data) {
    var nodes = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var node = data[i];
        nodes.push({
            id:             node.id,
            text:           node.name,
            attributes:     node,
        });
    }
    return nodes;
};

function loadPropertyGrid(node) {
    node = node || {id: '', text: '', attributes: {id: '', name: '', address: '', city: '', state: '', zip: '', phone: ''}};

    $('#pg').propertygrid('loadData', [
        {name: "ID", value: node.attributes.id, group: "", editor: 'text'},
        {name: "Name", value: node.attributes.name, group: "", editor: 'text'},
        {name: "Address", value: node.attributes.address, group: "", editor: 'text'},
        {name: "City", value: node.attributes.city, group: "", editor: 'text'},
        {name: "State", value: node.attributes.state, group: "", editor: 'text'},
        {name: "Zip", value: node.attributes.zip, group: "", editor: 'text'},
        {name: "Phone", value: node.attributes.phone, group: "", editor: 'text'},
        ]);
    $('#pg').propertygrid('fitColumns');
};

function getData() {
    return [
        {id: 1, name: "Tom Jones", address: "123 Blah Lane", city: "Somewhereville", state: "XY", zip: "12345", phone: "123-456-7890"},
        {id: 2, name: "Sally Sue", address: "162 Foobar Dr", city: "Blechtown", state: "QZ", zip: "98672", phone: "345-123-5432"},
        {id: 3, name: "Ralph Slug", address: "1762 Uknow St", city: "Mumbleville", state: "WE", zip: "21763", phone: "828-462-1786"},       ];
};

function getPgColumns() {
    return [[
        {field: 'name', title: 'Item', width: 30, sortable: true, resizeable: true},
        {field: 'value', title: 'Value', width: 70, resizeable: true},
        ]];
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Set up Fabric.Js Canvas
    var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('cv');     
    var gridWidth = 1000; // define canvas grid width
    var gridHeight= 1000; // define canvas grid height

    canvas.clear(); // Clear (remove) all objects off the canvase
    setSelectionStyle(); // Set canvase selection style
    drawGrid(gridWidth, gridHeight, 20); // Draw a grid on the canvas

    // Bind the event listeners for the canvas
    var canvasWrapper = document.getElementById('cv_wrapper');
    canvasWrapper.addEventListener('startdrag', handleStartDrag, false);
    canvasWrapper.addEventListener('stopdrag', handleStopDrag, false);
    canvasWrapper.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter, false);
    canvasWrapper.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
    canvasWrapper.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave, false);
    canvasWrapper.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);

    // Draw something on the canvas
    var grp = new fabric.Group([]);
    var r1 = new fabric.Rect({left: 0, top: 0, width: 50, height: 50, fill: '#f00'});
    var r2 = new fabric.Rect({left: 25, top: 25, width: 50, height: 50, fill: '#00f'});

    grp.addWithUpdate(r1);
    grp.addWithUpdate(r2);
    canvas.add(grp);
    canvas.renderAll();

    loadPropertyGrid(); 

function setSelectionStyle() {         
        canvas.selectionColor = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.3)';
        canvas.selectionBorderColor = '#f33';
        canvas.selectionLineWidth = 2;
};

function drawGrid(gridWidth, gridHeight, gridSize) {
        // to manipulate grid after creation
        var grid = new fabric.Group([], {
            left:                   0, 
            top:                    0,
            lockRotation:           true,
            lockScalingX:           true,
            lockScalingY:           true,
            hasControls:            false,
            hasBorders:             false,
            hasRotatingPoint:       false,
            lockMovementX:          true,
            lockMovementY:          true,
            selectable:             false,
            });

        // define presentation option of grid
        var lineOption = {stroke: 'rgba(0,0,0,.4)', strokeWidth: 1, selectable:false, strokeDashArray: [3, 3]};

        // vertical lines
        for(var i = Math.ceil(gridWidth/gridSize); i--;){
            grid.add( new fabric.Line([gridSize*i, 0, gridSize*i, gridHeight], lineOption) );
            }

        // horizontal lines
        for(var i = Math.ceil(gridHeight/gridSize); i--;){
            grid.add( new fabric.Line([0, gridSize*i, gridWidth, gridSize*i], lineOption) );
            }

        // add group to canvas
        canvas.add(grid);
        }; 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="easyui-layout" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <!-- WEST (LEFT SIDE) -->
        <div data-options="region:'west',split:true" title="EasyUI Tree Widget" style="width:240px;overflow:hidden">
          <div class="easyui-layout" style="width:100%;height:100%">
            <div data-options="region:'north',split:true" style="height:60%">
              <!-- Network Device Tree -->
              <ul class="easyui-tree" data-options="
                data: getData(),
                loadFilter: function(data) { return loadFilter(data); },
                onClick:    function(node){ loadPropertyGrid(node); },
                dnd: true,
                onDragEnter: function(e){ handleDragEnter(e); },
                onDragOver: function(e) { handleDragOver(e); },
                onDragLeave: function(e) { handleDragLeave(e); },
                onDrop: function(e) { handleDrop(e); },
                "></ul>
            </div>
            <div data-options="region:'center'" title="EasyUI PropertyGrid" style="height:40%">
              <!-- Property Grid -->
              <table id="pg" class="easyui-propertygrid" style="width:100%" data-options="
                method:'get',
                showGroup:false,
                scrollbarSize:0,
                columns: getPgColumns(),
                ">
              </table>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- CENTER -->
        <div data-options="region:'center',title:'Fabric.js Canvas',iconCls:'icon-ok'">
            <div data-container="FabricCanvas" id="cv_wrapper">
                <canvas id="cv" class="canvas-container" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi JWhitten, and welcome to SO. I think it would be better you post the relevant parts of your code, so that we can understand why you are *getting nothing*. Good luck.

Comment: @JCHOMEL - Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question to include a example of what I'm doing.